# How to map native SQL query to dto object in hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I have the following native SQL query:

```
Select E.id AS ID, E.desc AS DESCRIPTION FROM TEMP E
```

And the dto class:

```
private int id;
private String description;
/* getter and setter */
```

How to get a list of dto class??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     Query query = getSession.createSQLQuery("...")
     .addScalar("ID")
     .addScalar("DESCRIPTION")
     .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(dto.class));
     List<dto> list = query.list();



    dto class 
    @Entity
    @Table(name="your database table")
    public class DTO {

    @Id
    private int id
    @Column(name="description_name_on_table)
    private String description
    ..getter and setter 
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the alias "ID" is named "id" in class

Comment: yeah you can add annotation there @id this way it will map to dto

Comment: what about description?

Comment: is there any ways for ignore case ?

Comment: @column(name="database_description_field_name") put on description

Comment: I'm using xml mapping, could it be a problem?

Comment: no I dont think it will be problem and also I have edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

What I would probably do to maximize reuse would be to write my own `ResultTransformer` that you could instantiate prior to running your query and as a part of this implementation, you're required to provide it with the appropriate mapping information.

```
// construct the transformer and register mappings
MappedResultTransformertransformer = new MappedResultTransformer(DtoClass.class);
transformer.map( "ID", "id" );
transformer.map( "DESCRIPTION", "description" );

// apply the transformer
session.createQuery( ... ).setResultTransformer( transformer ).list();
```

Here's an example of how the transformer might look.

```
public class MappedResultTransformer extends BasicTransformerAdapter {
  final Map<String, String> fieldMappings = new HashMap<>();
  final Class<?> clazz;

  public MappedResultTransformer(Class<?> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public void map(String alias, String property) {
    fieldMappings.put( alias, property );
  }

  @Override
  public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
    Object result = clazz.newInstance();
    for ( int i = 0; i < aliases.length; ++i ) {
      Object tupleValue = tuple[ i ];
      String alias = aliases[ i ];
      String propertyName = fieldMappings.get( alias );
      if ( propertyName != null ) {
        // use reflection to set the value of 'propertyName' on 'result'
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

The beauty here is that this class is completely reusable, it isn't tied to any specific class or query.  You then could extend upon it and add support for nested properties, etc perhaps.

Comment: No, I showed you how taking `BasicTransformerAdapter`, which is a NOOP (does nothing) implementation of `ResultTransformer` can be extended into a reusable component for situations like this.  Please read what I wrote.